# Piping filename from grep to head

Tags: bash, grep, head

I'm in the process of rebuilding a database that has been corrupted, and part of this rebuild involves using grep via a simple bash script I've written to search for a string of around four words in length. This returns a file path, which I'd like to pipe directly into head so that I can view the first few lines of the file that grep has found.

However, while running `sh search2.sh "these are some search terms"` returns precisely one file path, running `sh search2.sh "these are some search terms" | head` doesn't run head on that file. I've noticed that the file path that grep returns doesn't escape spaces, but I don't know if this will be a problem for head. Any ideas what I should try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
head "$(search2.sh 'these are some search terms')"
```

this should resolve an issue with unquoted whitespace...

Answer (score 1):

Piping some data into head will cause only the first few lines of data to be displayed. What you want to do instead is calling head to display the beginning of each file found. You can do so by piping the data into `xargs` which will call `head` with the lines as its command line parameters:

```
sh search2.sh "these are some search terms" | xargs head
```

If you want to handle spaces in your paths, you will have to tell grep to return only filenames (`-l`) and zero-delimited paths (`-Z`), then use the `-0` switch on xargs to parse zero-delimited paths, e.g. to search for files containing "TEST" recursively from the current directory and calling `head` on them:

```
grep -lZR "TEST" . | xargs -0 head
```

Comment: `xargs` is overkill if `search2.sh` is guaranteed (though perhaps not) to return a single path.

Comment: I agree, as long as the single path is guaranteed. This solution should work with multiple paths, though.